# Is it possible to make a model look diamond encrusted?

Tags: modeling, svg

I have something that I'd like to achieve but I'm not sure if it's even possible to do. I basically have a mesh of a logo that I imported from an svg file, then converted to 3D using "Mesh from curve" option. I'm wondering if it's possible to make the mesh look diamond encrusted within blender? So far I can only think of racking up alot of polys to do something like this. I'm quite new to blender and would like to export this to a portable format if possible. Maybe there's a texture I could use to achieve this? I've been at a loss for a while now.

Thanks.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add reference images that might help us understand what you want to do. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))